# Convert string to guid in DataColumn

Tags: c#, .net, datacolumn

How do you convert a DataColumn of GUIDs set as type `string` to a DataColumn of GUIDs where the type is `Guid`? A column in the source data has the wrong type and I cannot change it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to womp's answer the following option:

4. After you get the table full of the data you can add a new DataColumn to the Columns of the data table this way:

   ```
   DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("GUIDColumnName",typeof(Guid),"StringColumnName");
   DataTableObj.Columns.Add(dc);
   ```

This will not have a performance hit if your data volume is huge.

Answer (score 3):

Once the datatable has been populated with data, you can't change the column type.  There's a few approaches you can take:

1. If you're using a `DataAdapter` to fill the table, you can use [`DataAdapter.FillSchema()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/229sz0y5.aspx) to get the structure of the table first.  Then you can modify the column type, and then fill it with data.
2. Take the initial table and clone it, change the column type on the new table, and then use [`DataTable.ImportRow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) to import each row from the old table.
3. Create a new column, copy the values from the old column to the new column, and delete the old column.